# A model of smooth projective plane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry

Is there a  model of [smooth projective plane](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412500v4.pdf) $(P,L,F)$  with the  following  property?

> The point space $P$  admits a Riemanian metric such that for  every point $p\in P$ and  every  line $\ell_{1}$ not  containing $p$, there is  a  line $\ell_{2}$ passing  $p$  such that $\ell_{1} \bot \ell_{2}$?

Comment: I suppose you mean besides the standard projective planes over the real, complex and quaternion fields with their Fubini-Study metrics.

Comment: @BenMcKay  I am not  even aware  of  this situation. Is  this  perpendicularity true  in this particular  metric?

Comment: It is true in the standard projective planes, because the tangent spaces of the lines passing through a point are precisely the (real, complex or quaternionic) 1-dimensional subspaces, and so any the result follows from the fact that the Fubini-Study metric at each point is (real, Hermitian, quaternionic Hermitian). For any 2-dimensional smooth projective plane, the same argument applies.

Comment: The same argument applies as well for the standard octave projective plane.

Comment: @BenMcKay  Thanks  for  your  comments. What  are  models  without this  property?

Comment: I don't know if there are any others with this property, or if there are any others without this property. A very nice question.

Comment: Assuming that the lines are _closed geodesics_ in the space of points, the result is clear - choose a line joining $p$ to a point in $\ell$ with least distance to $p$. The standard Riemannian models of $\Bbbk P^2$, $\Bbbk=\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb H$, $\mathbb O$ all have this property. So the question is: are there exotic smooth projective planes without a Riemannian metric as above?

Comment: @SebastianGoette  thank you for your comment.Where did you use the closed ness of geodesics?

Comment: To show that a point of least distance to $p$ exists on $\ell$.

Comment: You are just using that the line is compact (true in all topological projective planes), you don't need to make the lines into geodesics of the Riemannian metric. In fact, if you could do that you would just have the standard projective plane.

Comment: @AliTaghavi, the answer is yes and any Riemannian metric will do. The argument is that of Sebastian. If you ask that the perpendicular line be unique, then that might be more interesting. I have to think about it.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva:  I do not understand your claim:  It is clearly not true, if one takes an arbitrary Riemannian metric $g$ on $P$, that, for a point $p\in P$ and a line $\lambda\in\Lambda$ that is not incident with $p$, any point  $q$ incident with $\lambda$ of minimal $g$-distance from $p$ will have the property that the line $\mu$ incident with both  $p$ and $q$ meets $\lambda$ $g$-orthogonally (at $q$).  That's not even true for the standard projective structure on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ if you put a metric on it for which the lines are not geodesics.

Comment: @RobertBryant:   You are perfectly right, I confused the second line $l_2$ for a geodesic despite my protestation that lines (in part., $l_1$) did not have to be geodesics.

Comment: However doesn't the result follow from a simple argument like: the set of lines perperdicular (for any Riemannian metric in a real smooth projective plane) to a line is a non-contractible curve in the dual plane and so is the set of all lines passing through the non-incident point and thus both curves must meet?

Comment: @alvarezpaiva:  That is basically the argument that I gave in my answer below, though I use Sard's Theorem instead, since actually proving that the set of lines meeting a given line perpendicularly is a non-contractible curve in the dual plane (which is, of course, obvious in the flat case) seemed to me to be longer.  Of course, one should note that this argument only works in the 2-dimensional case.  Indeed, in the higher dimensions, it's most likely not true.

Comment: The set of lines perperdicular to the line $l_1$ can be easily deformed to the set of all lines passing through the non-incident point $p$: at each point $x$ in $l_1$ consider the angle between the perpendicular line and the line joining $x$ and $p$ and deform by changing the angle.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva:  That's a reasonable argument.  I didn't think of that, though.  However, since the argument I gave works using the cohomology groups $H^2(\cdot,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ (oddness of degree of a mapping between two non-orientable surfaces) and since the argument that two non-contractible loops in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ must meet also relies on these groups, I think that they are essentially the same in the end.  I wrote the argument out in detail because the OP would undoubtedly want to see the details.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank  you  again  for  your  answer. Undoubtedly  without  the  details  you added I  can not understand  your  deep answer. I   admit that I  have  to  think a lot  on this  expanded version.

Comment: @BenMcKay  for  RP2 is  this argument true (and   more   straightforward) : the  geometry  of  RP2 is  the  same  as the  geometry of   S^2 and  the condition under  my  question is  obvious  in S^2( perpendicularity  condition)?Since  geodesics  of  S^2  maps  to  line  of  RP^2(which  are  also  geodesics). Can this  intuitive  argument  be  applied  for  higher dimension? Another question: Let  we replace the  condition "every two lines  intersect  at one points"  by  "every two  lines intersect at two points" Does this implies that (in smooth  2  dimensional  case) the  manifold  is  S^2?

Comment: @alvarezpaiva  why the minimum distance implies that perpendicularity?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, please read the whole exchange between Robert and I.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer and a comment:

First, the partial answer:  If the dimension of $P$ is $2n=2$, then I believe that this orthogonality property holds for any Riemannian metric that one chooses on $P$.  Here is the argument:

Fix a Riemannian metric $g$ on $P$.

For a given line $\lambda\in\Lambda$, let $N_\lambda\subset P\times \Lambda$ consist of the pairs $(p,\mu)\in F$ for which $(p,\lambda)\in F$ and $T_p\bar\mu$ is $g$-perpendicular to $T_p\bar\lambda$.  (Here, I am using the standard notation $\bar\lambda$ to denote the curve of points (which is a smooth embedded submanifold of dimension $1$) in $P$ that are incident with $\lambda\in\Lambda$.)  Then $N_\lambda$ is an embedded circle in $P\times\Lambda$ that projects bijectively onto $\bar\lambda\subset P$.

Let $K_\lambda\subset N_\lambda\times P\subset P\times\Lambda\times P$ denote the set of triples $(p,\mu,q)$ such that $(q,\mu)\in F$ and $(p,\mu)\in N_\lambda$.  (In other words, $(p,\mu,q)\in K_\lambda$ if and only if $\mu$ is a line incident with $q$ such that $\bar\mu$ and $\bar\lambda$ meet $g$-orthogonally at $p$.)  Then the projection $\pi(p,\mu,q)=(p,\mu)$ makes $K_\lambda$ into a circle bundle over $N_\lambda$ that is a Klein bottle topologically (and smoothly).  The map $\sigma(p,\mu)=(p,\mu,p)$ is a smooth section $\sigma:N_\lambda\to K_\lambda$.

Now, the projection $\psi(p,\mu,q) = q$ is a smooth map $\psi:K_\lambda\to P$.  If $(p,\lambda)\in F$, then, one knows that $\psi^{-1}(p) = (p,\mu,p)$ where $\mu$ is the unique line such that $(p,\mu)\in N_\lambda$.  Moreover, $\psi:K_\lambda\to P$ is easily seen to induce a diffeomorphism from an open neighborhood of $\sigma(N_\lambda)$ in $K_\lambda$ onto an open neighborhood of $\bar\lambda$ in $P$.  It follows that $\psi:K_\lambda\to P$ is of 'odd degree'; consequently, for regular $\psi$-values $q\in P$, the cardinality of $\psi^{-1}(q)$ is odd.  (Note that this 'oddity' is the best one can do because both $P$ and $K_\lambda$ are *non-orientable* compact surfaces without boundary.)  In particular, $\psi$ is surjective, since, if $q\in P$ were not in the image of $\psi$, it would be a $\psi$-regular value with an even number of preimages.  Thus, for any $q\in P$ there exists a $(p,\mu,q)\in K_\lambda$.  By definition, $\bar\mu$ passes through $q$ and meets $\bar\lambda$ $g$-orthogonally (at $p$).

Second, the comment: I think this 'orthogonality property' does not hold in general when the dimension of $P$ is $2n>2$.  The problem (and the reason that the proof above does not work when $n>1$) is that it may not be possible to find a metric $g$ such that, for every $\lambda\in\Lambda$, the corresponding set $N_\lambda$ defined above is a copy of $\bar\lambda$.  The reason is that the condition that, for each $p\in \bar\lambda$, the $g$-orthogonal subspace to $T_p\bar\lambda\subset T_pP$ be the tangent $n$-plane to a $\mu\in\lambda$ such that $p$ lies on $\bar\mu$ now puts severe algebraic restrictions on the metric $g$, potentially more restrictions than can be satisfied by any metric.

To see why, consider the case $n=2$, which could be a small but 'arbitrary' deformation of the incidence relation of complex lines in $\mathbb{CP}^2$.  Then, at a point of $p$, the set of $2$-planes that are tangent to the surfaces $\bar\lambda$ for $(p,\lambda)\in F$ is a $2$-sphere $\Sigma_p$ embedded in the Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}_2^+(T_pP)$ of (oriented) $2$-planes in $T_pP\simeq\mathbb{R}^4$, which has dimension~$4>2$.  Such a $\Sigma_p$ has to be 'approximately' the standard 'diagonal' embedding of $\mathbb{CP}^1\simeq S^2$ into $\mathrm{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^4)\simeq S^2\times S^2$, but, as far as I can see, that's about all you can expect to know about it for an 'arbitrary' small deformation of the standard structure.  The 'generic' such $2$-sphere will not be preserved under the involution $E\to E^\perp$ induced on $\mathrm{Gr}_2^+(\mathbb{R}^4)$ by any metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$.  (After all, there is only a $9$-parameter family of such involutions.)  In fact, generically, what you would expect is that $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^\perp$ would only meet in a finite number of points, no matter which metric $g$ you chose in order to define the perpendicular. (Even worse, when $n=4$ or $8$, you wouldn't expect $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^\perp$ to meet at all for most metrics $g$.)

The upshot is that, one expects that, for a generic small perturbation of the standard smooth projective plane structure in dimension $2n=4$, for any metric $g$ on $P$, the set of pairs of lines that meet $g$-orthogonally will be a rather small set, too small to provide the orthogonality relations needed to satisfy this orthogonality property.

Comment: Prof  Bryant, Thank  you  very  much  for your  interesting answer. I  try to  understand its  detail.